# Why has everything gone very small?

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu on my laptop; however, everything displays very small.  The resolution is at 1080p, which it has been at since I started using the OS.  It just started to load up like this for some reason after a few days.  I have included the menu for comparison and I have zoomed in on the web browser to 140% to make it readable for me.  How do I fix this?

[image]